# Wrong level displayed in HMENU when using "entryLevel" attribute

Tags: menu, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript

I have followed all available instructions, but the following TypoScript does not do what it is supposed to:

```
lib.menu.mainMenu = HMENU
lib.menu.mainMenu {
    entryLevel = 0
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO = 1
        NO {
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
            allWrap = <li>|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li>|</li>
        }
        CUR = 1
        CUR {
            allWrap = <li>|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li>|</li>
        }
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
            allWrap = <li>|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li>|</li>
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of displaying (always!) the first level of the page structure, the second level is shown, and so on. Particularly leaf nodes lead to an empty menu bar. I don't understand this, the diverse manuals clearly state that only the first level will always appear if no other level is defined! So how could it be that, e.g. the second level is displayed in the same way if it is not defined?

Typo3 version: 6.1.5

Comment: Did you verify that there are no other definitions of lib.menu.mainMenu in your TypoScript? Please check this in the TypoScript Object Browser.

Comment: Actually, I have also tried changing it to "lib.mainMenu". In addition, a second menu "lib.subMenu" should provide all remaining menu entries (with 3 levels of TMENU; entryLevel=1). However, the second one doesn't work correctly either. It ignores the level definition and only displays the child nodes of the current page. I have also checked with the demo material, that was copied during the installation. The menu scripts in fileadmin/default/TypoScript/Menu (firstLevel and secondLevel) produce the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible reasons for this behavior is that somewhere in the rootline (probably on the first level) you have a **template record** that has "**Rootlevel**" set. Therefore this is then considered (at least in `HMENU`s) the root page and `entryLevel = 0` thus produces subpages of this page.

Comment: OK, I think I am getting the basic idea, but how should I avoid this? My understanding is that I need a template with rootlevel set, otherwise TYPO3 complains about a missing template when accessing the frontpage.

Comment: I think I have found the real cause based on your recommendation. Perhaps I wanted to much in the first iteration steps. As I desire a slightly different template on the home page, I thought that assigning an extended version for the next level is accurate. But I included the original root template as (static?) basis for the extended version. That obviously caused the problem. But then the further question is how to set up this scenario correctly? Nevertheless: accepted (best) answer for my original question!

Comment: I suggest you post a new question for that. Different templating techniques might require different approaches. From what you wrote I understand that the root page is your homepage. That's something I never do. On all the TYPO3 installations that I manage, the root page of the website (not the absolute root with UID 0) is a **shortcut** to the homepage that is a subpage of that root page.

Comment: That is true, I have adpoted this approach from the example data; and I think I have read it somewhere. But your suggestion makes totally sense. I was not aware that every item in the page tree can be changed to a link. This should do the trick, otherwise I will post a new question. Thank you!